# J2SE SDK configuration in oracle sql developer

Tags: .net, sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I installed oracle SQL developer on my machine. When I try to open sqldeveloper.exe, I get a popup that prompts me to select a file path for java.exe

I have java.exe at `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe`

When I try to proceed, I get an error message

```
Cannot find a J2SE SDK installed at path C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\java.exe
```

I also tried moving java.exe file one folder upwards i.e. in `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\` But I still keep getting the same error.

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 4):

SQL Developer won't run on Java 64 bit.  The reason SQLdev needs a full JDK is for the ability to perform debugging which is only included in the full JDK.

You can download the Java SE Development Kit 6 32 bit via [this link](http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/6u45-b06/jdk-6u45-windows-i586.exe).
([Other versions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u45-oth-JPR))

Your J2SE SDK path will be similar like this: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45`

you can find the SQL Developer configuration file at:

```
[ORACLEHOME]/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf
```

Answer (score 4):

there is some conflict between communicating between java and oracle
so oracle is installing an specific java for it self .

try to insert this address :

```
[ORACLEHOME]\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\jdk\jre\bin\java.exe
```

remember [ORACLEHOME] means where your oracle has installed

Answer (score 0):

Run SQL Developer as administrator.(works for me)